# laravel DB existence check

Tags: php, database, laravel, web

i want to make website which has 'like' and 'dislike'

i made controller

```
public function addLike($id)
{
    $feeling = new Feeling();
    $feeling->post_id = $id;
    $feeling->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $feeling->like = 1;

    $feeling->check = 1;

    if ($dd = DB::table('feelings')->where('post_id',  $feeling->post_id)->where('user_id',  Auth::user()->id)->get()) {
        dd($dd);
        return redirect()->route('post.show', ['feeling' => $feeling, 'id' => $id]);
    } else {
        $feeling->save();
        return redirect()->route('post.show', ['feeling' => $feeling, 'id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

i thought `if(feeling is $feeling = new Feeling`, and Feeling is my like,dislike model)
when feeling's post number and user number exist on feelings table,
i just return redirect

else, if post number and user number both doesn't exist together
i want to save and direct

but i have problem ->>>
when post number and user number both doesn't exist together,
i checked my web doesn't work properly so i put dd($dd), and saw

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#360 ▼
  #items: []
}
$dd = DB::table('feelings')->where('post_id',  $feeling->post_id)->where('user_id',  Auth::user()->id)
dd($dd)
```

had made this kind of empty array.

how can i check feeling's post number and user number's existence?

Comment: an empty collection would still be evaluated to true so you need another mechanism to check if the collection is empty or not. One is to use `isNotEmpty` method, as in: `..->id)->get()->isNotEmpty()` Or use `exists` method Refer here:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-isnotempty

Answer (score 1):

An empty collection would still be evaluated as `true` inside the if statement. There are different ways to check for the existence of records in Larave.

One is `exists()`

```
$exists = DB::table('feelings')->where('post_id',  $feeling->post_id)->where('user_id',  Auth::user()->id)->exists();
//$exists returns true is record exists, otherwise false
```

Check if record collections is empty or not using `isEmpty()` or `isNotEmpty()`:

```
$empty = DB::table('feelings')->where('post_id',  $feeling->post_id)->where('user_id',  Auth::user()->id)->get()->isEmpty();
//$empty returns true if no result
```

Refer here to check available methods:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Comment: @lagbox my bad it was supposed to be calling `isEmpty()` after calling `get()`. Thanks.